# Find out by how many days two date ranges overlap in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

I have two arbitrary date ranges, for example:

```
2019-01-01 - 2019-01-10
and
2019-01-06 - 2019-01-20
```

How do I find out in PHP, by how many days these date ranges overlap? (In the example above it's 5 days)

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Is it always given in order, or can it be reversed as well?

Comment: There is no code yet, since I do can't find out any example on how to do this. I could only find a way to see IF the ranges overlap but not by how many days. I thought about making the dates into DateTime objects but substracting them shows differences between just two dates, not date ranges.

Comment: Qirel: I can order the ranges from older to newer if needed.

Comment: Are the values strings?

Comment: Yes, but i can  make them into datetime objects or cast them into any needed type or format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) objects:

```
$range1 = '2019-01-01 - 2019-01-10';
$range2 = '2019-01-06 - 2019-01-20';
list($start, $end) = explode(' - ', $range1);
$start1 = new DateTime($start);
$end1 = new DateTime($end);
list($start, $end) = explode(' - ', $range2);
$start2 = new DateTime($start);
$end2 = new DateTime($end);
if ($end1 > $start1) {
    $overlap = $end1->diff(min($start2, $end2));
}
else {
    $overlap = $start1->diff(min($start2, $end2));
}
echo "overlap is " . ($overlap->format('%a') + 1) . " days";
```

Output

```
overlap is 5 days
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AlhZB)

**Update**

Here is a more robust version of the code that allows for arbitrary overlapping of the ranges (including one being contained entirely in the other):

```
function range_overlap($range1, $range2) {
    list($start, $end) = explode(' - ', $range1);
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end =  new DateTime($end);
    $start1 = min($start, $end);
    $end1 = max($start, $end);
    list($start, $end) = explode(' - ', $range2);
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end =  new DateTime($end);
    $start2 = min($start, $end);
    $end2 = max($start, $end);
    // check for special cases
    if ($start1 >= $start2 && $end1 <= $end2) {
        // range1 completely contained inside range2
        $overlap = $start1->diff($end1);
    }
    elseif ($start2 >= $start1 && $end2 <= $end1) {
        // range2 completely contained inside range1
        $overlap = $start2->diff($end2);
    }
    elseif ($end2 > $end1) {
        // range1 ends first
        $overlap = $start2->diff($end1);
    }
    else {
        // range2 ends first
        $overlap = $start1->diff($end2);
    }
    // if overlap is < 0 then there is no overlap
    $overlap_days = $overlap->invert ? 0 : ($overlap->format('%a') + 1);
    echo "overlap is $overlap_days days\n";
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
range_overlap('2019-01-01 - 2019-01-10', '2019-01-06 - 2019-01-20'); // 5 days
range_overlap('2019-01-01 - 2019-03-20', '2019-05-06 - 2019-04-20'); // no overlap
range_overlap('2019-01-10 - 2019-05-20', '2019-01-01 - 2019-05-20'); // 131 days
range_overlap('2019-01-06 - 2019-01-20', '2019-01-10 - 2019-01-01'); // 5 days
range_overlap('2019-01-30 - 2019-01-10', '2019-01-12 - 2019-01-15'); // 4 days
range_overlap('2019-02-01 - 2019-03-20', '2019-01-10 - 2019-02-28'); // 28 days
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0g61b)

Comment: Doesn't appear to work correctly, if i change the ranges to say $range1 = '2019-01-10 - 2019-05-20';
$range2 = '2019-01-01 - 2019-05-20';, it only shows 20 days overlap

Comment: @Askerman sorry, typo in the last line. See my edit, it should work now.

Comment: Works great now.

Comment: @Askerman I hadn't allowed for overlaps longer than 30 days, for which you need to use the `%a` format rather than `%d`

Comment: @Askerman I've updated my answer with a more robust solution that will allow for more combinations of range overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, what you want to do, but check this solution:

```
<?php

$date1 = strtotime('2019-01-01');
$date2 = strtotime('2019-01-10');

$date3 = strtotime('2019-01-06');
$date4 = strtotime('2019-01-20');

$dateDiff1 = $date2 - $date1;
$dateDiff2 = $date4 - $date3;

$finalDiff = $dateDiff2 - $dateDiff1;

echo round($finalDiff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

**Return:**

5

More info about [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

**Notice:** It will work only if second dates are always bigger that first ones. Your question is not clear.

Comment: `$dateDiff1 = max($date1, $date3);
$dateDiff2 = min($date2, $date4);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use:

```
function nightsInRange(\Datetime $arriveDate, \Datetime $departDate, \Datetime $rangeStart, \Datetime $rangeEnd) : int
{
    // just use the Y-m-d portion of date
    $arriveDate = clone $arriveDate;
    $arriveDate->setTime(0,0,0);

    $departDate = clone $departDate;
    $departDate->setTime(0,0,0);

    $rangeStart = clone $rangeStart;
    $rangeStart->setTime(0,0,0);

    $rangeEnd = clone $rangeEnd;
    $rangeEnd->setTime(0,0,0);

    if ($arriveDate >= $departDate) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("arriveDate must be BEFORE departDate");
    }

    if ($rangeStart > $rangeEnd) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("rangeEnd must be greater than or equal to rangeStart");
    }

    $arriveDateInRange = ($arriveDate >= $rangeStart && $arriveDate <= $rangeEnd);
    $departDateInRange = ($departDate >= $rangeStart && $departDate <= $rangeEnd);

    if ($arriveDateInRange && $departDateInRange) {
        // both dates inside range
        $nightsInRange = $arriveDate->diff($departDate)->days;
    } elseif ($arriveDateInRange && !$departDateInRange) {
        // arrive inside, depart outside
        $nightsInRange = $arriveDate->diff($rangeEnd)->days + 1;
    } elseif (!$arriveDateInRange && $departDateInRange) {
        // arrive outside, depart inside
        $nightsInRange = $departDate->diff($rangeStart)->days;
    } elseif ($arriveDate <= $rangeStart && $departDate >= $rangeEnd) {
        // arrive before rangeStart, depart after rangeEnd
        //
        // Note that we add 1 to the date diff to get the range length.  For
        // example, the range from 2018-11-01 to 2018-11-30 is 30 days (not 29).
        // A range with same start and end dates (e.g. 2018-11-01 to 2018-11-01)
        // would have a range length of 1 day.
        //
        $nightsInRange = $rangeStart->diff($rangeEnd)->days + 1;
    } else {
        // no overlap
        $nightsInRange = 0;
    }

    return $nightsInRange;
}
```